# Using SSIS, Inserting File Names Into Sql-Server After Writing C# ScriptTask to Get File Names

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a directory of Excel files that includes the date in the file name; they represent reports.  I have already imported all the data into sequel server from the excel files but need to attach the date from the File Name to each of those records that were imported into Sql-Server.

Example Dir List.

```
A_201008.xls
A_201009.xls
A_201010.xls
...
...
...
```

The following is my C# ScriptTask to fill an array of File Names:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO

public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\S\Apps\Files\", "A*.xls*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            int Flag = 0;
            string dir = @"\\S\Apps\Files\";
            string[] files1;
            int numFiles;
            files1 = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            numFiles = files.Length;


            for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
            {
                string file = files[i].ToString();

                int file1 = file.IndexOf(dir, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

                if (file1 != -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(file);

                    Flag = 1;
                }
            }

            if (Flag == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Matches Found");
            }



            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

The MsgBoxes are the just for testing the script and will be removed.

My question is this.  What is the protocol in SSIS to grab the File Names from my array to insert them in the relevant rows of my table in SQL-Server?

Please Note that I already know what to do to trim the file names for the date.

Thanks

Comment: For all the files in the folder, you want to record that those files existed to some table? Do you care whether you shove them all in as a single shot or can you insert one file name, insert the next, etc

Comment: I have a ForEach Loop Container in SSIS that has already looped through all the files and imported the data into Sql-Server (millions of rows).  I now need to grab the date from the FileName (i.e. 201010) and insert it into a Date column in Sql-Server for each row of the relevant report date from the FileName.

Comment: @billinkc For Example, A_201008.xls has thousands of rows and each of those rows has to have the date of the report (coming from the File Name) in the date column. A-201009.xls also has thousands of rows and each of those rows hast to have the date...etc.  It is important to note that ALL of the data from the reports have been imported to the same table.  So all the dates need to be inserted into the relevant date column.

Comment: To restate, you are importing file data. You'd like to add an additional column to the import to provide metadata about the source?

Comment: Correct....Id like to import the date from the file name into a current table in Sql-Server.  I just wrote a c# script to get the file name.  I would like to use SSIS to import the date from the File Name into a current table in SQL-Server